# How do I convert WGS84 lat,long points from degrees to meters in Python?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, proj

I am facing a problem in the creation of heat map based on the lat-long points. All the points are closely packed into a group like squares, so I would like to convert the lat,long points to meters so that I can plot it over the graph to see the variation in the heatmap.

Current my points are in WGS84 (4326) format.
How can I convert projection coordinates into the meters so that I can plot the heat map?

Comment: There is no such thing as WSG84. Please stop uncorrecting it.

Comment: you can use basemap in python.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the library [pyproj](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyproj?), that allows you to change the coordinate system. I use EPSG3035 that is convenient for Europe, but depending on where your points are you might have to use a different one.

```
import pyproj
import numpy as np

lon1 = 2
lat1 = 48

lon2 = 2
lat2 = 49

x1, y1 = pyproj.transform(wgs84, epsg3035, lon1, lat1)
print(x1, y1)

x2, y2 = pyproj.transform(wgs84, epsg3035, lon2, lat2)
print(x2, y2)

# a Pythagore's theorem is sufficient to compute an approximate distance
distance_m = np.sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)
print(distance_m)
```

The error will be typically of a few percents for points in Europe, depending on where they are and how far they are.
Have a nice day !

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the Python bindings for GDAL/OGR.  This contains a module called OSR that can be used to reproject your geometries.  See the GDAL Cookbook [here](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/projection.html).  To display in meters, you will need to choose a suitable CRS.  Your choice will depend on where you are in the world and your use-case.